# Return a string if first two characters of integer are 34

Tags: ruby

I would like to know how to return a string if a set number of characters entered equal a set value. If the integer begins with these two numbers puts this

I've looked at string `start_with?` but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Show what you tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand, you want something like this:

```
puts "Please enter your number:"
number = gets.chomp

result = number.to_s.start_with?("34") ? "Starts with 34" : "Doesn't start with 34"

puts result
```

Create a file with that code (eg. `test.rb`) and in your command line run `ruby tet.rb`.

```
Please enter your number:
3456
Starts with 34
```

Comment: No need for `.to_s` there, btw.

Comment: Yeap, I got used to doing `.to_s` in my production code :) But you are right, there was no need to do it here (+1).

Answer (score 0):

These work if you either have an array of string integers where you want to locate a number, or if you require the user to input the number themselves, or if you're searching a string with more than just numbers in it. It depends what you want really!

```
arr = %w{4758 4759 123 097 384764} # an array of numbers

p arr.find{|x| x.start_with?('38')} # '38' can be replaced with number of your choosing
#=> '384764'

#OR 

input = gets.chomp #user input

p input if input.start_with?('38') # '38' can be replaced with number of your choosing

#OR you can use regex to find a matching number in the input

str = "Here's one number 95875 and another 65786"

p str.scan(/95\d*/) # 95 are the first two digits of the number you're looking for
#=> ["95875"]
```